# New MacBook Pro 13" Red spot on the screen

Tags: macbook-pro

I purchased a brand new 13" MacBook Pro from Pakistan,Asia 2 days ago.

The screen has a red spot near the middle. What could be the cause of this?

And what shall I do in this case? Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the anti-glare coating on your MacBook's screen is damaged. You should take it back to the store and ask for service or the anti-glare coating replacement.

Comment: I wouldn’t focus on the coating.  There are dozens of pixels malfunctioning. Get a web chat or support ticket opening and ask Apple to diagnose what’s wrong. I wouldn’t speculate  and I would just ask for advice how to have the black uniform and even.

Answer (score 0):

Clean the screen carefully to make sure it is not just something ON the screen. If that doesn‘t help it‘s a hardware issue. As you device as new, take it to the store or an authorized service provider to get the MacBook or screen replaced under warranty.